# Amazon S3 upload issues with Ruby on Rails using Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong to upload my file to s3 using carrierwave. I am able to store files locally using only ruby but I need to use carrierwave to store them to s3. I am getting an error I believe deals with setting the correct aws information but I did that. I lack a lot of knowledge as I am just a beginner with ruby on rails. I want to directly upload files to a s3 bucket which I think I have configured with CarrierWave. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced

View:

```
%div
  %h3 Import a CSV File
  = form_tag import_orders_path, :class => 'order-uploads', multipart: true do
    = file_field_tag 'upload[file]'
    / :file for just getting param[:file] from server
    %br
    = submit_tag "Import CSV", :class => 'submit-file'
```

Initializer file(I added this manually so maybe this is a problem?)

carrierwave.rb

```
require 'fog'
require 'carrierwave'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'my_key_id',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'secret_access_key',                        # required
    :region                 => 'us-east-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'my_bucket'                          # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                        # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>"max-age=#{365.day.to_i}"} # optional, defaults to {}
end
```

What I am trying but it fails:

```
uploader = AvatarUploader.new
uploader.store!(param[:upload][:file])
```

Error I get:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5362ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5362ms
** [Airbrake] Notice was not sent due to configuration:         
  Environment Monitored? false         
  API key set? false
** [Airbrake] Notice was not sent due to configuration:         
  Environment Monitored? false         
  API key set? false

NameError (undefined local variable or method `path' for #<OrdersController:0x00000007637ea8>):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:14:in `import'



NameError (undefined local variable or method `path' for #<OrdersController:0x00000007637ea8>):
  app/controllers/orders_controller.rb:14:in `import'


  Rendered /home.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /home.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /home.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /home.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /home.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (892.2ms)
  Rendered /home.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionpack-4.1.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb (892.2ms)
```

This works for local storage:

```
 name = params[:upload][:file].original_filename
 directory = "public/files"
 path = File.join(directory, name)
 File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:upload][:file].read) }
 flash[:notice] = "File uploaded"
```

Comment: As a starting point just usual checklist items for S3 that rather concern the AWS side: does the user with this key and secret have s3:PutObject grant? is CORS config relevant for your case?

Comment: And, BTW... if I may suggest -- if you are going to use **only** S3, I would go for `carrierwave-aws` gem. Fog is a monster and I had rather a bad experience with it. `carrierwave-aws`is pretty lean and works well for me.